# awt & swing alternative for headless environment

Tags: java, swing, awt, jsf-2.2, headless

I'm using thirdparty libraries to read data from a card reader (electronic identity cards). I implmented it in my webpage in my JSF2.2 project with maven and it runs on my local weblocic 12.2 just fine. 
The libraries use awt and swing to show a GUI with status messages to the user while processing the card (e.g. "Please insert card,...). 
But on our server it won't run because the server is running in headless environment. Unfortunately I can't change the servr configuration.
Is their an alternative for awt and swing libraries that I can use to overwrite the UI and that runs in a headless environment?

Comment: Rhand: see the abovelinked dupes. The first dupe explains why your idea won't work. The second dupe answers the X of your http://xyproblem.info

Comment: @BalusC: I indeed missed the 'show gui' part and focussed to much om my experience with rendering pdf's which also requires some swing and awt classes and works with a headless solutiuon. Will remove my comment.